# Additional sign in dimension

Tags: footprint, kicad

I'm inserting new footprint in kicad. I'm not good in mechanics as I should be. When I learned mechanics in school, no one told me how to interpret something like this:

> Number - (Diameter-sign) Number

I want to use dimensions from:
[image: Dimensions]

On the right side of picture there are PTH pads with this kind of dimension.

How should I interpret that dimension?

Comment: Why don't you insert a picture instead of a potentially unsafe attachment?

Comment: One moment. I will add attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number before the hole diameter specification tells you how many holes there are of this type. It is up to you to then spot where those holes are. For example, 4 - ⌀3.5 PTH is telling you that there are 4x 3.5mm diameter Plated Through Holes - in this case one at each corner of the LCD.

Please note that there is a mistake in this datasheet, as 10 holes are specified for the connector at the edge (10 - ⌀1.0 PTH) but 12 are shown and labelled.

Comment: So this is as I thought - it's pad number. But this 10 pads misleaded me. Also, I can't find info about offset of this bigger (mounting) pads.

Comment: That's because there is no information regarding the position of those pads in that drawing. Welcome to the wonderful world of terrible datasheets. I suggest using a pair of callipers to  measure them by hand :)

Comment: Will do this, when I buy this module. I tried milions of datasheets of various devices, but this is most terrible ever.

Answer (score 2):

Number - indicates how many holes/pads/whatever.

Ø - indicated the diameter of the hole/pad around it.

The mounting holes for example... There are 4 (in the 4 corners), with a through hole of 3.5mm, and a clearance pad around them of 5.0mm.